# region of convergence of the series $\sum _{-\infty}^{\infty} 3^{-|n|}z^{2n}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I am trying to find the region of convergence of the series $$\sum _{-\infty}^{\infty} 3^{-|n|}z^{2n}$$ but because of negative $\infty$ I am not sure how to find. Can anyone help me. Thanks

Comment: Split the series into two parts, one for negative $n$, one for non-negative $n$. The series converges where both parts, $$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{-1} 3^{-\lvert n\rvert} z^{2n} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} 3^{-k}\biggl(\frac{1}{z}\biggr)^{2k}\quad\text{and}\quad \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 3^{-n}z^{2n}$$ converge.

Answer (score -2):

this series is equal to $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}3^{-n}z^{2n} $ which is equal to the function $ \frac{1}{1-(z/\sqrt{3})^{2}} $